# APp/.flowconfig Could not start Flow server! Server_start_failed (exit, 8)

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, flowtype

```
[APp/.flowconfig] Could not start Flow server! [Server_start_failed (exit, 8)]
```

I am attempting the resolve this issue.
I changed my react version to ^0.153.0 after I
had an error saying the version didn't match.
As soon as I change the version to the right one
being "0.153.0" I get this error.

```
[APp/.flowconfig] Could not start Flow server! [Server_start_failed (exit, 8)]
```

What do I do?

Picture of my screen:
[image]

Comment: Can you please show what's on the outputs tab and change the dropdown to show flow output?